# Ошибка SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064. Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

При попытке зарегестрироваться получаю ошибку

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ilike ? limit 1' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where `username` ilike Admin limit 1)
```

Что это и куда смотреть?

Comment: смотрите в свой sql-запрос, фрагмент которого вы же и привели.

Comment: MySQL пытается тебе сказать, что он ни разу не PostgreSQL и слова "ilike" не знает...

Comment: А если бы и знал, то всё равно не хватает кавычек, должно быть `'Admin'`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, MYSQL  не может найти оператор "ilike" в SQL.  MySQL нет такого оператора, но в некоторых других СУБД он есть. НО MySQL можно использовать оператор LIKE и переделать запрос следующим образом:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE 'Admin' limit 1
```